# ReadfromKafka stuck and messages are not passed to WriteToBigQuery

Tags: python, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to read a large Kafka topic and insert those message to a BigQuery table from the beginning of the topic using a beam pipeline using Python SDK deployed in GCP Dataflow.

Following is my Pipeline settings and this work correctly when trying to read data from small topics.

```
pipeline
        |"Read Kafka Messages" >> ReadFromKafka(
            consumer_config={
            'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_servers,
            'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest',
            },
            topics=input_topic_list,
            )
        |"Decode JSON to Dict" >>  Map(lambda record: convert_kafka_record_to_dictionary(record))
        |'Write To BigQuery' >> WriteToBigQuery(
           bq_table,
           insert_retry_strategy=RetryStrategy.RETRY_NEVER,
           write_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
           create_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER
           )
```

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this issue?

I tried adding `beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(5))` to the pipeline and this didn't have any impact at all.

Comment: You seem to be missing a `group.id` consumer config?

Comment: It have tried passing group.id also in the consumer_config. It didnt help.

Comment: You should keep it. Then you can try using tools like `kafka-consumer-groups --describe` to monitor the consumer process to see if any offsets are being committed back to the group. Otherwise, the "size" of the topic ultimately shouldn't matter, but if you do much windowing, then you'd expect to get an OOM error rather than just a "stuck" consumer